# Trying to print the registers' values from the stack using a pin tool

Tags: c++, c, debugging, instrumentation

I am trying to print out the stack in different routines using a pin tool. I am able to get all of the routines but I am a little confused on how to get the addresses stored in the registers in the stack of that routine.

What I have is this:

```
VOID SETRTN_CONTEXT(CONTEXT * ctxt)
{
   ADDRINT reg_address;

   PIN_SaveContext(ctxt, &m_ctxt);
   reg_address = PIN_GetContextReg(&m_ctxt, REG_STACK_PTR);
}
```

and in another function I have this piece of code that calls that function:

```
for(rtn = SEC_RtnHead(sec); RTN_Valid(rtn); rtn = RTN_Next(rtn) )
{
   RTN_Open(rtn);
   RTN_InsertCall(rtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)SETRTN_CONTEXT,
      IARG_CONST_CONTEXT, IARG_THREAD_ID, IARG_END);
   RTN_Close(rtn);
}
```

I am a little confused on when the routine calls that function since I am only getting one result and I get it after attaching with Pin and waiting a couple of seconds.

Any pinheads that might help me on this one? I understand that I need the context from a routine in order to get the registers but I cannot find any function that returns the context as an object...

Comment: This seems specific to the pin tool you are using. Have you tried looking at its documentation? I believe [this](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/publicity/pin/docs/39599/Pin/html/index.html) is it.

Comment: Why not just use a user-mode debugger?

Comment: Yes I went all over their documentation and couldn't find anything helpful. It is not too specific -- all of the functions that are being used in this piece of code are from the Pin API, I am just not getting any results whatsoever.. @slavik262

Comment: What do you mean by user-mode debugger? @JonathonReinhart

Comment: A debugger like GDB, or MS Visual studio, etc. These will allow you to step through your code (at the assembly level, if you wish), and see the stack, registers, etc.  Other debuggers like Olly (or Immunity) allow you do this easily for programs you don't have the source to as well.

Comment: I'm not trying to discredit the use of instrumentation tools, I'm just pointing out that if this is an exercise for experimentation or learning, a debugger is much more suited for the task.

Comment: No, I am trying to get data from a running process. It is for research purposes.. @JonathonReinhart

Comment: You can attach to a running process with the above mentioned debuggers. Or, APIs like `ptrace` allow you to do this programmatically.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking on doing it with ptrace but I already started with pin and been working with it for a while now. I cannot be very specific but for my purposes working with a regular debugger wouldn't be useful. I do something with the data inside the program, it is not only for debugging purposes @JonathonReinhart

Comment: Sounds sketchy to me. I'm not sure why you're asking on stack overflow then, if you are unwilling to explain your purpose. Therefore, I am unwilling to help.

Comment: Well, it is my master's thesis... It is not nothing sketchy at all. But I respect your point of view. @JonathonReinhart

Comment: Do you want the value of the stack pointer register or the content of the stack itself?

Answer (score 0):

In your RTN_InsertCall, you add the thread id, and in your SETRTN_CONTEXT function declaration you don't receive the thread id... might want to fix that.

Also, in your analysis routine SETRTN_CONTEXT, you're not actually saving anything external to the application. I could be wrong if m_ctxt is a global variable that you're manipulating elsewhere, which how could that be sound unless you did that for every time the analysis routine ran and in a thread safe way?

Clearly, you want to write the information to some file or output. I recommend using some kind of xml tool; this makes it easy to parse, and if you write your pintools smartly, you can exchange the format of the output by obeying some interface contract.

Also to clarify your confusion, you try to insert the analysis routine to run before every single function in a particular image; every time that function is called in that image, your SETRTN_CONTEXT runs.